# I wrote this simple code but i get " File ended while scanning use of \beamer@howtotreatframe. " and cant figure out what the problem is

Tags: beamer

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}

\title{Tracking im Internet} \author{Petros Kladis} \date{06.Juni.2020}

\begin{document}
    \frame{ \maketitle }
    \frame{\frametitle{Gliederung} \tableofcontents }
        \section{Einleitung}
        \section{Cookies}
        \section{Was passiert mit unsere Data}
        \section{Wie kann ich es vermeiden}
            \frame{\frametitle{Warum habe ich das Thema ausgewählt?}
                \begin{itemize}
                \item Big Data
                \item Wie wird man getracked
                \item Was kann damit machen
                \item Online Sichercheit
                \end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Is your final `\frame` missing its `}` ?  Or was that a copy/paste error?

Comment: That was it i overlooked it completly, thanls

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by @Teepeemm's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your final frame is missing it's closing `}`.  But really, for a frame that long, it's probably better to use `\begin` and `\end`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}

\title{Tracking im Internet} \author{Petros Kladis} \date{06.Juni.2020}

\begin{document}
    \frame{ \maketitle }
    \frame{\frametitle{Gliederung} \tableofcontents }
        \section{Einleitung}
        \section{Cookies}
        \section{Was passiert mit unsere Data}
        \section{Wie kann ich es vermeiden}
            \begin{frame}
                \frametitle{Warum habe ich das Thema ausgewählt?}
                \begin{itemize}
                \item Big Data
                \item Wie wird man getracked
                \item Was kann damit machen
                \item Online Sichercheit
                \end{itemize} 
           \end{frame}
\end{document}
```